# How to calculate claimable rewards from dApp Staking on Astar and Shibuya across multiple eras and multiple dApps?

Tags: polkadot-js, astar, era, rewards, shibuya

Hi~ I have some questions about the developer staking process.
I am using polkadot-api, developer staking part on shibuya-network.

At [portal.astar.network](https://portal.astar.network/), I can see staking info on the **dApp Staking** dashboard.

1st_Question)
"Available to claim" shows "#-Era". If I claim 1 Era, how much SBY can I get?
On my Test Result, I got 0.00181..SBY by calculating on 'Not Re-stake after claiming' option 'off'. `( [after-transferable-balance] - [prev-transferable-balance] + [claim-transaction-fee] = [1 Era-Reward] ).`
Can you give me some feedback about the above actions or some other guide?

2nd_Question)
I try to retrieve by using the API wth:

```js
await api.query.dappsStaking.generalStakerInfo(staker, getDappAddressEnum(dAppCa));
```

Where `staker` is a user-wallet and dAppCa is an EVM Contracts Account.
The result returns Quantity of SBY that staked at Era like below:
`[currentEra : 2828 | Available to claim : 18 Era]`.

```
{
  "stakes": [
    { "staked": "0", "era": "2,805" },
    { "staked": "7,000,000,000,000,000,000", "era": "2,811" },
    { "staked": "7,007,761,889,397,804,870", "era": "2,817" }
  ]
}
```

How can I get "Available to claim-Era" by using polkadot-API?

How can I get 'A-staker' staking "dApp-list and each dApp's staked value" by using polkadot-API?

I just want to get the above information, like below function returns.
If 'staker-wallet-address' staked on `"dApp-A : 7 SBY, 3Era", "dApp-B : 5 SBY, 4Era", "dApp-C : 9 SBY, 8Era"`

```
input-parameter(staker-wallet-address) =>
{ 
  "dApp-A" : ["3Era(Meaning-Reward)", "7 SBY"],
  "dApp-B" : ["4Era(Meaning-Reward)", "5 SBY"],
  "dApp-C" : ["8Era(Meaning-Reward)", "9 SBY"]
}
```

3rd_Question) How is the 'Available to claim'-value increased by the staking quantity and multi-dAapp Staking situation like in the above example?

Where can I get some infomation about my questions above? thx~^^

Comment: may I ask you to join our Astar group chat and discuss about this?
https://t.me/astar_kr please tag me(@rheeunion) after you join.

Comment: This sounds like a request to explain the whole dApps stalking. Please take a look at the [docs](https://docs.astar.network/docs/dapp-staking/), [code](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-frame/tree/polkadot-v0.9.39/frame/dapps-staking), [precompile](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/EVM/precompiles/) first and for discussions please join the Astar Discord

Comment: this question should be broken into multiple questions. i recently asked a similar question in the Astar Discord dApp Staking channel https://discord.com/channels/644182966574252073/890479283124994048 since the Astar UI currently allows you to claim rewards but doesn't yet display how many rewards are available to be claimed.